# Performance problem with saving images locally and writing to api in Swift 4

Tags: swift

We are transforming images to a byte array and then saving them as a string in a JSON file. This happens locally on the file system. When reading this JSON file from the file system or writing it to the API the performance is really bad. For large quantities of images you have to wait >10 sec, before it is loaded in the ViewController. Is there a better way or library (Swift4) to deal with this? We are already compressing the quality to 0.2. Someone told us to use base64, is this the way to go?

We encode the image like this:ImagesBytes : [[UInt8]]? in to a JSON File with some TextField data.

This is the code

`public var formImagesBytes : [[UInt8]]? = []` So this is in the model as a field. The model is a form with fields(strings) and an array of images which is an array of UInt8. This will be first saved locally while decoding it like this:

`formImagesBytes = try container.decodeIfPresent([[UInt8]].self, forKey: .formImagesBytes)`

Then we JSON encode all the data, including values of the form and image array of bytes. Then we add it with the Filemanager to the local storage on the device. We can open this file and it is including the formdata and an array of bytes in this case.

When loading the data from the local storage in the viewcontroller we again read this local file en decode it to a form model. But processing this file is taking too much time. I hope it is clear. My question is not really about the code, but about: is there a best practice or better way to write the image to this JSON file in order to let the app perform better.

Example output:

```
{"Images":[[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,144,0,144,0,0,255,225,0,140,69,120,105,102,0,0,77,77,0,42,0,0,0,8,0,5,1,18,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,26,0,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,74,1,27,0,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,82,1,40,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,135,105,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,1,0,3,160,1,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,160,2,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,82,160,3,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,253,0,0,0,0,255,237,0,56,80,104,111,116,111,115,104,111,112,32,51,46,48,0,56,66,73,77,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,56,66,73,77,4,37,0,0,0,0,0,16,212,29,140,217,143,0,178,4,233,128,9,152,236,248,66,126,255,192,0,17,8,0,253,1,82,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,129,145,161,8,35,66,177,193,21,82,209,240,36,51,98,114,130,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,196,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,129,8,20,66,145,161,177,193,9,35,51,82,240,21,98,114,209,10,22,36,52,225,37,241,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,219,0,67,0,28,28,28,28,28,28,48,28,28,48,68,48,48,48,68,92,68,68,68,68,92,116,92,92,92,92,92,116,140,116,116,116,116,116,116,140,140,140,140,140,140,140,140,168,168,168,168,168,168,196,196,196,196,196,220,220,220,220,220,220,220,220,220,220,255,219,0,67,1,34,36,36,56,52,56,96,52,52,96,230,156,128,156,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,255,221,0,4,0,22,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,223,162,138,40,16,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,1,255,208,223,162,138,40,16,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,1,255,209,223,162,138,40,16,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,1,255,210,223,162,138,40,16,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0,81,69,20,0]],
```

Here is a screenshot:

[Output of the Image in a ByteArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsoBz.png)

Comment: If you are not using base64, how do you encode the images to a string right now?

Comment: We use an array of bytes like this : ImagesBytes : [[UInt8]]

Comment: In that case I would give base64 a try. Should be fairly quick to implement

Comment: It would be a really helpful idea for you to update your question with relevant code showing us what you are doing. Hard to help when there's no code.

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply I will try it. I do not completely understand what base64  in this case, will the characters be less than when you use a [[Uint8]]

Comment: I have edited the question with some code I hope this helps. I think the question gets out of scope if I post all the code relating to this. But if it is not clear I can post all the code relating to this process

Comment: Could you show us what the JSON looks like? Based on your description I would assume that bytes will be in the like "["byte1", "byte2", "byte3", ...]. That would explain why it would take forever to parse all the values individually

Comment: This is exactly the case, I have added a screenshot and the data that is written in JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you posted explains why it is taking so long to parse. It probably takes a while to parse these huge arrays. 
Instead of having each image as an array of bytes it should just be one base64 encoded string for each image. Something like this:

```
public var formImagesBase64 : [String]?
```

Here is some Swift code that might help you:

```
// Encoding Image
let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
let b64string = data?.base64EncodedString()

// Decoding image
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: b64string!)
let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
```

Comment: I will try this. But what I don't really understand is how base64 can make it quicker to load en for example post images to an API. I've tried base64 encoding on a string and saw that it makes the output even bigger in characters. So which element makes it faster with base64?

Comment: I think the problem in your case is that the JSON parser needs to parse this huge array and afterwards put the bytes together. So the issue is not the length of the json but its structure. With base64, every image just becomes ONE string (instead of a huge array) which is a lot less work for the parser. Encoding/Decoding base64 is very fast and should be no problem.